# Is it possible to create an archive containing files with identical name?

Tags: archiving, filenames

Is it possible to create an archive in whatever format containing files with identical name located in the same folder? If yes, how?

I need this for some testing purposes. The target OS is Windows. Thank you.

Comment: How can you have have 2 with identical names in the same folder?

Comment: Or in English:  How have can you have 2 files with identical names in the same folder?

Comment: This is my question :) In other words, can someone guarantee that it is never possible?

Comment: what are you testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least tar and cpio should be able to handle that. GNU tar won't care if you add a file twice, for example:

```
tar cf foo.tar bar baz bar
```

That should create a tar archive containing the file 'bar' twice.

Answer (score 0):

If a file is appended to a tar archive, at least with GNU tar, that already exists then tar does some [weirdness](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Advanced-tar.html#SEC58) which boils down to when you extract/delete, only the last appended copy is extracted / deleted.